# Charts .js update when array changes

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a relatively simple question about charts.js that I can't get working.

I have a function that makes an ajax call and changes the values of an array after it runs a few calculations.

I want my chart to display each of these values array[0] --> array [9] once the array has updated, but the chart seems to just remain static no matter what I do.

my code:

***SETUP THE CHART:***

```
window.onload = function(){
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
    responsive: true
    });
};
```

***SETUP THE CHART DATA:***

```
var lineChartData = {
    labels : ["1","2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
    datasets : [
        {
            label: "CreepSlain Analysis",
            fillColor : "rgba(40,35,100,0.2)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
            pointColor : "#FFFFFF",
            pointStrokeColor : "#000000",
            pointHighlightFill : "#000000",
            pointHighlightStroke : "#000000",
            data : [hmcArray[0],hmcArray[1],hmcArray[2],hmcArray[3],hmcArray[4],hmcArray[5],hmcArray[6],hmcArray[7],hmcArray[8],hmcArray[9]]
        }
    ]
};
```

***THE CHART'S APPEARANCE WHEN ARRAY IS EMPTY:***

[image]

***CODE TO CALCULATE VALUES OF HMC ARRAY:***

```
function calculateHmc(aF,bF,cF,dF,eF,fF,gF,n) {

    var pvpFactor = ((aF * killArray[n]) + (bF * assistArray[n])) / (cF * deathArray[n]);
    pvpFactor = pvpFactor.toFixed(2);
    pvpFactorArray.push(pvpFactor);
    var pveFactor = ((dF * csArray[n]) + (eF * jungleCSArray[n]) + (fF * counterJungleCSArray[n])) / ((gameTimeArray[n])/60);
    pveFactor = pveFactor.toFixed(2);
    pveFactorArray.push(pveFactor);
    var auxFactor = (gF * crowdControlArray[n]);
    auxFactor = auxFactor.toFixed(2);
    auxFactorArray.push(auxFactor);

    var rawHMC = (0.8 * pvpFactor) + (0.4 * pveFactor) + (2.5 * auxFactor);
    hmcArray.push(rawHMC);

//The array gets updated with hmcArray.push(rawHMC);

... continued
```

***CHART'S APPEARANCE AFTER ARRAY IS UPDATED:***

[image]

Do I have to run some sort of function that will re-draw the chart? And if so, how do I do this?

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: I'd make it a custom [tag:knockout.js] binding and then apply that binding on an observable component.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

```
.update( )
```

**Calling update() on your Chart instance will re-render the chart with any updated values, allowing you to edit the value of multiple existing points, then render those ione n imatanred eendr loop.**

```
myLineChart.datasets[0].points[2].value = 50;
// Would update the first dataset's value of 'March' to be 50
myLineChart.update();
// Calling update now animates the position of March from 90 to 50.
```

I got it working with the following code, let me know if there's a more efficient way to do it!

```
window.myLine.datasets[0].points[0].value = hmcArray[0];
window.myLine.datasets[0].points[1].value = hmcArray[1];
window.myLine.datasets[0].points[2].value = hmcArray[2];
window.myLine.datasets[0].points[3].value = hmcArray[3];
window.myLine.datasets[0].points[4].value = hmcArray[4];
window.myLine.datasets[0].points[5].value = hmcArray[5];
window.myLine.datasets[0].points[6].value = hmcArray[6];
window.myLine.datasets[0].points[7].value = hmcArray[7];
window.myLine.datasets[0].points[8].value = hmcArray[8];
window.myLine.datasets[0].points[9].value = hmcArray[9];
window.myLine.update();
```